# What is the difference in time complexity between these two blocks of code (if any) and why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime, time-complexity

Trying to solidify my knowledge about Time Complexity. I think I know the answer to this, but would like to hear some good explanations.

```
main = []
while len(main) < 5:
    sub = []
    while len(sub) < 5:
        sub.append(random.randint(1,10))
    main.append(sub)
```

VS

```
main = []
sub = []
while len(main) < 5:
    sub.append(random.randint(1,10))
    if len(sub) == 5:
        main.append(list(sub))
        sub = []
```

Comment: `main = [random.choices(range(1,11),k=5) for _ in range(5)]` would solve it faster. You included partly unneded calls to functions that could be optimized.

Comment: True, but the T Stone asked about time complexity, not run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity in both are `O(1)` - constant time because they both perform a constant number of operations as @Yakov Dan already stated.

This is because time complexity is usually expressed as a function of a variable number(say `n`) and tends to show how changing the value of `n` will change the time the algorithm will take.

Now, assuming you had `n` instead of 5, then you would have `O(n^2)` for both cases. It may be tricky for the second case since a basic way of checking the polynomial complexity is to count the number of nested loops and you can be lead to conclude that the second version is `O(n)` since it has a single loop.

However, carefully looking at it will show you that the loop runs `n`(5 in this case) times for `sub` for each value appended to `main`, so it is essentially the same.

This of course assumes that the in-built `list.append` is atomic or runs in a constant time.

Comment: Thanks Ken4scholars. Good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference, since the time complexity is constant in both cases - you perform a constant amount of operations both times.

Comment: Can you please answer the same question in case number `5` replaced with `n`? I think there is a change in time complexity.

Comment: The time complexity would be O(n^2), again in both cases. Assuming `append` is constant time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)